# iPhone add icon in status bar (a la Battery Indicator)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, statusbar

I was wondering if it is possible to add an icon to the iPhone status bar, much like the battery and wifi indicator. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As previously reported, it's not possible to do so with the SDK.

If you're working for a jailbroken environment, status bar icons need to be placed within /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app with two versions: Default_NAME.png and FSO_NAME.png. Default is used in the light menubar-like status bar, FSO on the home screen or apps that use the black status bar.

SBStatusBarController has a method called addStatusBarItem:, just call it with @"NAME" as your argument and it will handle the rest for you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't really make app store apps, I'm not going to pay $100/year for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not even possible to access the status bar directly, I wouldn't think so. You can only indirectly set a few of the status bar's properties through UIApplication, the displayed icons are not one of them. Everything else is Apple's turf.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this. The `UIApplication` class gives you some limited controls over appearance. You may want to file an enhancement request with [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa).

Comment: i am not working for a jailbroken device or environment. i want to show app icon in status bar (left side). is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it in the sdk, plus apple would pitch a hissy fit if somebody was able to do it.  I know there's a way to do it with the jailbroken tools, but I don't think I should discuss that stuff here as there are other sites that discuss it

Comment: What's wrong with discussing it here? As long as the answer make it clear it's only possible when jailbroken, I don't see an issue.

Comment: because chances are none of us have the answers he wants, if he goes to a site that "specializes" in just using the jailbroken tools then he has a better chance of getting an answer

Comment: Some members of the jailbroken scene browse Stack Overflow every once in a while; whenever I see something that could be solved in a jailbroken environment, I try to point it out.