# How to add an icon into iphone/ipod status bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, icons, statusbar

Does Apple not allow developers to add an icon into a status bar?

I followed code from a book. The code is simple:

```
@interface UIApplication (extended) 
- (void) addStatusBarImageNamed:(NSString *)aName; 
- (void) removeStatusBarImageNamed:(NSString *)aName; 

@end 

- (void)performAction{
    if (xxx) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]addStatusBarImageNamed:@"Default_EN.png"];
    }
    else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]addStatusBarImageNamed:@"Default_EC.png"];

    }
}
```

But it gives the following feedback :

> -addStatusBarImageNamed: is deprecated. Doing nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: Any updates on this with the new sdk releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Classes/YourViewController.m**, the **addStatusBarImageNamed:removeOnExit:** method needs to be overwritten with this.

```
- (void) addStatusBarImageNamed:(NSString*)image removeOnExit: (BOOL) remove {
if(_statusbarimage!=nil && _responds) {
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"statusBarEnabled"] integerValue] == 1)
[self removeStatusBarImageNamed:_statusbarimage];
statusbarimage=image;
}
if (_responds) {
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"statusBarEnabled"] integerValue] == 1)
[super addStatusBarImageNamed:image removeOnExit: remove];
}
}
```

See if it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

To my best knowledge, this isn't permitted within the **SDK**, but there could be the possibilities that they could have some private API to do so but so far they haven't exposed those, I think you are'nt able to add icon in status bar. **If someone know please correct me .**

Comment: Correct, this is private API. And even deprecated API, this will lead straight to an App Store rejection.

Comment: +1 - Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391059/iphone-add-icon-in-status-bar-a-la-battery-indicator as well.

Comment: thanks @Nick Weaver @WebberLai:  also read the **SO** link provided by @Nick Weaver.